# What type of probe can measure induced drag in the wake?

Tags: drag, wind-tunnel, measurement

Induced drag can be measured from velocity preturbation in Treffz plane.

1. In Treffz plane what velocity direction is important for induced drag, vertically down, lateral(horizontal, "spanwise") or all possible angles?
2. What probe  I need to measure induced drag in the wake and how probe must be oriented?
3. How far from wing I must install probe, velocity die with distance from wing, so every location will get different magnitudes and directions?

Comment: If you measure flow field velocities, how do you split between e.g. friction drag and induced drag?